# $x,y\geq 0$, $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $ x^3,y^3, x + y\in \mathbb{Q}$ prove that $ x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

What I have done so far:

$x+y\in Q \Leftrightarrow x+y= \frac{a}{b}$ ,with $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

$ \Leftrightarrow b(x+y)=a \Rightarrow b=1 \Rightarrow (x+y)\in \mathbb{N}$

So now how do I prove that $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 5):

If $x$ or $y=0$ then it is trivial. Otherwise $x+y>0$ and $x^3,y^3, x + y\in \mathbb{Q}$ imply
$$(x+y)^2-\frac{x^3+y^3}{x+y}=(x^2+2xy+y^2)-(x^2-xy+y^2)=3xy\in \mathbb{Q}.$$
Therefore $xy\in\mathbb{Q}$. Can you take it from here?

P.S. Let $p=x+y$ and $q=xy$, then $x,y$ solve $z^2-pz+q$. If $x\geq y$ then
$$\mathbb{Q}\ni x=\left(\frac{p+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right)^3\implies (3p^2+\Delta)\sqrt{\Delta}\in\mathbb{Q}\implies \sqrt{\Delta}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
with $0\leq \Delta=p^2-4q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ (and also $y=(x+y)-x$).

Comment: $3xy \in Q \Rightarrow xy \in Q$   $xy= \frac{a}{b}$ where $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $ a,b\in N$ $ \Rightarrow bxy=a \Rightarrow xy \in N$ I seem to struggle to get further at the moment

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy The product of your $x$ and $y$ is not rational. I used  the hypothesis $x,y\geq 0$ when I told that $x+y>0$.

Comment: @stenvik team $xy,x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$ are not sufficient to conclude that  $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Take for example $3\pm\sqrt{2}$. See my P.S.

Comment: +1 Nice answer: an alternative to the PS is: we have $xy \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $x^2 -xy +y^2 \in \Bbb{Q}$, so $x^2 +xy + y^2 \in \Bbb{Q}$, hence $x - y = (x^3 - y^3)/(x^2 + xy + y^2) \in \Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

$ (x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x+y) $ implies that $ xy $ is rational if $ x + y \neq 0 $. In this case, letting $ p = x+y $ and $ q = xy $, we have that $ x, y $ are roots of $ t^2 - pt + q $. Assume that $ x \notin \mathbf Q $. Then, this quadratic is irreducible and we have $ [\mathbf Q(x): \mathbf Q] = 2 $. However, the polynomial $ t^3 - x^3 $ is irreducible if it has no roots in $ \mathbf Q $, which gives $ [\mathbf Q(x) : \mathbf Q] = 3 $, contradiction.

Comment: I don't even know what " [Q(x):Q]=2" means, is this galois theory or something?

Comment: It is elementary field theory - denotes the degree of the field extension, i.e the dimension of the $ \mathbf Q $-vector space $ \mathbf Q(x) $.